# Print FTP output in a TextBox

Tags: vb.net

I have the .net vb code below which unfortunately does not work as intended.

1) On exit I cannot close the txtConsoleOut (textbox) (exception error occurs)

2) The hashes ##### (from the ftp code) does not appear instantaneously in TextBox called *txtConsoleOut* it only appears after the process (FTP) is completed.

The code below only requires one button called btnRun and one textbox called TxtConsoleOut

```
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Class form1
    Private psi As ProcessStartInfo
    Private cmd As Process

    Private Delegate Sub InvokeWithString(ByVal text As String)

    Private Sub CMD_Exited(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
         txtConsoleout.hide()
    End Sub
    ' This sub gets called in a different thread so invokation is required
    Private Sub Async_Data_Received(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataReceivedEventArgs)
        Me.Invoke(New InvokeWithString(AddressOf Sync_Output), e.Data)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Sync_Output(ByVal text As String)
        txtConsoleOut.AppendText(text & Environment.NewLine)
        txtConsoleOut.ScrollToCaret()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnRun_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRun.Click
        btnRun.Text = "Starting!!!"
        psi = New ProcessStartInfo("ftp", " -s:c:\compu\ftp-p.txt")

        Dim systemencoding As System.Text.Encoding =
            System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage)
        With psi
            .UseShellExecute = False  ' Required for redirection
            .RedirectStandardError = True
            .RedirectStandardOutput = True
            .RedirectStandardInput = True
            .CreateNoWindow = True
            .StandardOutputEncoding = systemencoding  ' Use OEM encoding for console applications
            .StandardErrorEncoding = systemencoding
        End With
        ' EnableraisingEvents is required for Exited event
        cmd = New Process With {.StartInfo = psi, .EnableRaisingEvents = True}
        AddHandler cmd.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf Async_Data_Received
        AddHandler cmd.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf Async_Data_Received
        AddHandler cmd.Exited, AddressOf CMD_Exited

        cmd.Start()

        ' Start async reading of the redirected streams
        ' Without these calls the events won't fire
        cmd.BeginOutputReadLine()
        cmd.BeginErrorReadLine()
    End Sub
    'Option Explicit
    'Private  Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
End Class
```

Comment: **1)** What's the exception you're getting? **2)** I know you must use invocation, but perhaps that's what locks the UI from updating?

Comment: This is the error I am getting :-

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'TxtConsoleOut' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: That means you gotta invoke the `txtConsoleOut.Hide()` too.

Comment: I am lost here ! How do i invoke txtConsoleOut.Hide()

Comment: The same way you invoked the `txtConsoleOut.AppendText()`!

Comment: Forgive me I am a newbie at this ; could you please show me in code how this is done . . .

Comment: Let me guess you didn't write this code yourself. Which .NET Framework are you targeting? 3.5 or lower, or 4.0 or higher? To find out see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772098(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: :( yes ! .net framework 2.0

Comment: **1)** Declare a new delegate with no parameters. **2)** Create a new method which calls `txtConsoleOut.Hide()` **3)** In the CMD_Exited sub call `Me.Invoke(New <delegate name here>(AddressOf <step 2 method name here>))`.

Comment: I am lost and i know this is beyond the scope of this forum but I really need some code examples preferably done in my existing code. Your assistance will much appreciated.

Comment: I just gave you some. What is now the problem? You already have one delegate declared in your code. Mimic it, but remove the `text` parameter. Then a method is simply writing `Private Sub <method name>() [new line] End Sub` and putting code in there. This is a good article explaining a bit of VB.NET's syntax: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/527aztek.aspx

Comment: Oh ! not to worry i got it :-)